# Ubuntu cannot boot (stuck on black screen)

Tags: boot, dual-boot

I cannot find the answer to my particular case at the forums. I had successfully installed ubuntu 16.04 with dual boot windows 10. But, the problem is I cannot boot into ubuntu, at least not in a normal way.

I can boot ubuntu from recovery mode (advanced option from grab menu), but every time I tried to boot it normally, I got stuck sometimes on a black screen. Sometimes, (after several reboots), I got to the ubuntu logo with progress dots, but I got stuck there again.

One time I was successfully able to boot normally, I don't know why or how (I had been trying every solutions I can find over this problem), but after restart, I got stuck on the black screen again.

Sometimes, some lines of code appear on the left top corner of the screen, and I got stuck there. No matter what I tried, I just cannot boot normally.

Please help. (I am a newb and this is my very first attempt to install ubuntu, the only OS I am familiar is windows)

Comment: Sometimes some lines of codes appear during black screen, and some lines says "BUG: soft lockup - CPU#3 stuck for 22s!" I have no idea what kind of bug it is but I cannot boot into the ubuntu OS :'(

Comment: And your graphics card is...?

Comment: It's Nvidia GTX 1060

Comment: Now, please, next time make sure to include all relevant information in the question itself. If requested to add more, then [edit] the question.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Here you go:

[image]

Are you on Nvidia Graphics card? If yes, then start in nomodeset instead of quiet and install nvidia graphics driver using terminal and restart, voila.

Permanent Solution : Start your system in nomodeset, after the system is up and running open terminal and add the graphics driver repo using 'sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers' then update using 'sudo apt-get update' then finally install the latest nvidia drivers using the command 'sudo apt install nvidia-384', after the installation is done, reboot your pc and you won't longer need to change it to nomodeset everytime you boot up, also you can install nouveau drivers instead nvidia, which are opensource and may be more stable than the nvidia one, if you don't do any extreme gaming on your Ubuntu then I'd suggest you to install the nouveau drivers.

Comment: I am using Nvidia, but I have no idea how to do those steps. I pressed "e" key in grab and can't find that quiet thing...

Comment: Select "Try Ubuntu, press 'e' for editing, find the line with "quiet splash" and type `nomodeset` before, after or instead of "quiet splash" (it doesn't matter, the point is to have the additional parameter/boot option.

Comment: I changed it and it worked! Thank you all for your help. But unfortunately, I had to change it to "nomodeset" everytime I tried to boot. In other words, the change did not get saved I think. :(

Comment: Start your system in nomodeset, after the system is up and running open terminal and add the graphics driver repo using 'sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers' then update using 'sudo apt-get update'  then finally install the latest nvidia drivers using the command 'sudo apt install nvidia-384', after the installation is done, reboot your pc and you won't longer need to change it to nomodeset everytime you boot up,  also you can install nouveau drivers instead nvidia, which are opensource and may be more stable than the nvidia one..

Comment: @MichaelBay, Also, I don't know why people on Ubuntu community has to be this rude, sorry for rambling you can delete this later, but c'mon, the guy's probably installing and dealing with Linux for the 1st time, there's no need to be this obtuse, I'm a final year IT engineering student and I have problems with hadoop installation and other stuff too, but overcome after some efforts, I'm a part of a lot other communities such as XDA and manymore but man the people in here are the most obtuse, it's okay being a noob, that's how people learn, guide the noobs rather than bringing them down, Peace.

Comment: Are you talking about me? Did I commented here and was deleted? Don't remember... Did someone else commented in a rude way? Please flag those comments.